# Snap svg .click alert not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, click, snap.svg

I have a click event bound to an SVG graphic, however the alert is not being fired upon click. I am using snap SVG.

```
greenBoySign = greenBoy.select('g#greenBoySign');


greenBoySign.click(function () {
  alert("button clicked");
});
```

The script has been set up to function once the DOM is ready.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to put a test example with the svg on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks dor answering. I resolved this issue in the end by shuffling some div's about as the click box was being obscured.